# need to check if two words ae equal in java

Tags: java

I have been solving this problem that states given two string arrays word1and word2, return true if the two arrays represent the same string, and false otherwise.

```
Input: word1 = ["ab", "c"], word2 = ["a", "bc"]
Output: true
Explanation:
word1 represents string "ab" + "c" -> "abc"
word2 represents string "a" + "bc" -> "abc"
The strings are the same, so return true.
```

In order to solve the above problem statement I have made the below java class but it is not working properly, please advise how to overcome from this

```
public class ArraysEqual {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<>(); // "a", "cb"
        List<String> l2 = new ArrayList<>(); // ["ab", "c"]
        l1.add("ab");
        l1.add("c");
        l2.add("a");
        l2.add("bc");

        final boolean b = arrayStringsAreEqual(l1, l2);
        System.out.println(b);

    }

    static boolean arrayStringsAreEqual(List<String> word1, List<String> word2) {
        String s = null, t = null;
        int n = word1.size(), m = word2.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            s += word1.get(i);
        for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) t += word2.get(i);
        return s == t;
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the quickest way to compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805601/whats-the-quickest-way-to-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: what problem are you facing here?

Comment: Two corrections are required: (1) `String s = "", t = "";` and (2) `return s.equals(t);`

Comment: Alternatively, one liner solution: `return String.join("", word1).equals(String.join("", word2));`

Comment: #ToSlow You could overload `arrayStringsAreEqual` to work on both `String[]` and `List<String>`: https://repl.it/@ShashSinha/HighActualFiber#Main.java